# Auto update icons

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

What I am currently trying to achieve is an auto icon updater. So far I only have it working for 1 icon, but I have 9. Now I have tried to repeat the same code 9 times, try to get it to work from the same file, ect... but to no success. Each icon has a separate timer which will show a different image. (Same image lower opacity)

I want a something which will check the database for the time and see if the time is up, show image 1 if not show image 2.

This is the code I have so far:

```
function runme() {
    var ajaxRequest;
    try {
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e) {
        try {
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    var str = "<?echo$id;?>";
    var strhehe = "&rand=" + Math.random();
    var strhehes = "&userid=<?echo$id;?>";
    var strhehess = "&username=<?echo$name;?>";

    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "auto.php?&id=" + str + strhehes + strhehess + strhehe, true);

    ajaxRequest.send(null);
    // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {

        if (ajaxRequest.readyState == 4) {
            if (ajaxRequest.status == 200) {
                attempt = 0;
                document.getElementById("icon_messaging").innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
                document.getElementById("error_mess").innerHTML = '';
                document.getElementById("error_mess").style.display = 'none';
            } else {
                attempt += 1
                document.getElementById("error_mess").style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById("error_mess").innerHTML = '<br><font color="#ff4040" onMouseover="ddrivetip(\'There is an error connecting. The game will continue trying to connect again.\')" onMouseout="hideddrivetip()"  style="cursor: pointer;">Error Code: ' + new XMLHttpRequest().status + '<br>Attempts: ' + attempt + '</font>';
            }

        }
    }
    setTimeout("runme()", 6000);
}
setTimeout("runme()", 5000);
```

**Here is auto.php:**

```
//AUTO INCLUDE

$userids = $_GET['userid'];

$saturate = "/[^a-z0-9]/i";
$saturatesd = "/[^0-9]/i";
$sessionid = preg_replace($saturate,"",$sessionidbefore);
$userid = preg_replace($saturatesd,"",$userids);


$statustest = mysql_query("SELECT newmail,lastactive FROM login WHERE id = '$userids' LIMIT 1");
$statustesttwo = mysql_fetch_array($statustest);
$mails = $statustesttwo['newmail'];

$last_active_1 = $statustesttwo['lastactive'];

if($mails == '0'){
    echo "<a id='inboxspan' href='/home.php?pageid=80'><img src='images/mail-yes.gif' style='border-style: none'></a>";
}else{
    echo "<a id='inboxspan' href='/home.php?pageid=80'><img src='images/layout/mail-n.jpg' style='border-style: none'></a>";
}
```

Comment: Please show code for `auto.php`.

Comment: auto.php has been added.

Comment: What is your exact problem? Do you see a request every 5 or 6 seconds in your Developer Tools? Do you see any errors being raised? What exactly happens and what exactly doesn't happen?

Comment: Sanitize your Query vars! Use mysqli or PDO. Mysql_* functions are deprecated! If you don't want to use mysql_real_escape_string() to sanitize all the variables that you use into your query!

Comment: What could happen if I don't "sanitize" it?

Comment: @SamHam If you don't sanitize it, someone can easily perform SQL injections. He could for example manually go to `/home.php?id=' or 1 --` ... leading him to see/access data he shouldn't. In this specific case he could for example see if someone else has mail by manually going to `/home.php?id=' or id='someone_elses_id` ... This is because eventually this means running this query: `SELECT newmail,lastactive FROM login WHERE id = '' or id='someone_elses_id' LIMIT 1`

Comment: @SamHam Now off course the impact isn't that big. But think about getting injections in queries like `select * from users where username='$username' and password='$password'` ... And imagine someone injecting `admin' -- ` in $username. The resulting query would then be `select * from users where username='admin' -- ' and password='xxxxx'` ... letting the injector log in as admin. (The `-- ` is sql comment sign, making everything after it being ignored) In some cases people can copy your entire database via sql injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function runme(icon) {

    var iconElementId;
    var iconTimer;
    switch (icon) {
        case "mail":
            iconElementId = "icon_messaging";
            iconTimer = 5000;
            break;
        case "gta":
            iconElementId = "gta_icon";
            iconTimer = <? echo $icon_secs[0]; ?>;
            break;
        case "burg":
            iconElementId = "c_icon";
            iconTimer = 5000;
            break;
        case "crimes":
            iconElementId = "crimes_icon";
            iconTimer = <? echo $icon_secs[1]; ?>;
            break;
        case "chase":
            iconElementId = "chase_icon";
            iconTimer = <? echo $icon_secs[2]; ?>;
            break;
        case "robbery":
            iconElementId = "robbery_icon";
            iconTimer = <? echo $icon_secs[3]; ?>;
            break;
        case "train":
            iconElementId = "train_icon";
            iconTimer = <? echo $icon_secs[4]; ?>;
            break;
        case "goods":
            iconElementId = "goods_icon";
            iconTimer = <? echo $icon_secs[5]; ?>;
            break;
        case "df":
            iconElementId = "df_icon";
            iconTimer = <? echo $icon_secs[6]; ?>;
            break;
        case "sm":
            iconElementId = "sm_icon";
            iconTimer = <? echo $icon_secs[7]; ?>;
            break;
    }

    var ajaxRequest;
    try {
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e) {
        try {
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    var str = "<?echo $id;?>";
    var strhehe = "&rand=" + Math.random();
    var strhehes = "&userid=<?echo $id;?>";
    var strhehess = "&username=<?echo $name;?>";

    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "auto.php?icon=" + encodeURIComponent(icon) + "&id=" + str + strhehes + strhehess + strhehe, true);

    ajaxRequest.send(null);
    // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {

        if (ajaxRequest.readyState == 4) {
            if (ajaxRequest.status == 200) {
                attempt = 0;
                document.getElementById(iconElementId).innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
                document.getElementById("error_mess").innerHTML = '';
                document.getElementById("error_mess").style.display = 'none';
            } else {
                attempt += 1
                document.getElementById("error_mess").style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById("error_mess").innerHTML = '<br><font color="#ff4040" onMouseover="ddrivetip(\'There is an error connecting. The game will continue trying to connect again.\')" onMouseout="hideddrivetip()"  style="cursor: pointer;">Error Code: ' + new XMLHttpRequest().status + '<br>Attempts: ' + attempt + '</font>';
            }

        }
    }
    setTimeout("runme('" + icon + "')", iconTimer);
}
setTimeout("runme('mail')", 5000);
setTimeout("runme('gta')", <? echo $icon_secs[0]; ?>);
setTimeout("runme('burg')", 5000);
setTimeout("runme('crimes')", <? echo $icon_secs[1]; ?>);
setTimeout("runme('chase')", <? echo $icon_secs[2]; ?>);
setTimeout("runme('robbery')", <? echo $icon_secs[3]; ?>);
setTimeout("runme('train')", <? echo $icon_secs[4]; ?>);
setTimeout("runme('goods')", <? echo $icon_secs[5]; ?>);
setTimeout("runme('df')", <? echo $icon_secs[6]; ?>);
setTimeout("runme('sm')", <? echo $icon_secs[7]; ?>);
```

Comment: Well, this is exactly my answer, without the PHP section and the explanation. No offense (and as long as it's good for the OP, it's good for everybody), but accepting this one was a weird move :D

Comment: This is exactly what he needed, so I put it up on here to get the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly, this is the updating system for the "new mail" icon, and you need to check and update other stuff too. Since you want separate timers, you could parametrize the `runme()` function. Your JavaScript could be modified like this:

```
function runme(icon) {

    var iconElementId;
    var iconTimer;
    switch (icon) {
        case "mail":
            iconElementId = "icon_messaging";
            iconTimer = 6000;
            break;
        case "news":
            iconElementId = "icon_notifications"; // I'm making up names and timeouts here
            iconTimer = 3000;
            break;
        case "something":
            iconElementId = "icon_something"; // Still making up
            iconTimer = 8000;
            break;
        /* And so on, covering all your 9 cases */
    }

    var ajaxRequest;
    try {
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e) {
        try {
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    var str = "<?echo $id;?>";
    var strhehe = "&rand=" + Math.random();
    var strhehes = "&userid=<?echo $id;?>";
    var strhehess = "&username=<?echo $name;?>";

    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "auto.php?icon=" + encodeURIComponent(icon) + "&id=" + str + strhehes + strhehess + strhehe, true);

    ajaxRequest.send(null);
    // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {

        if (ajaxRequest.readyState == 4) {
            if (ajaxRequest.status == 200) {
                attempt = 0;
                document.getElementById(iconElementId).innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
                document.getElementById("error_mess").innerHTML = '';
                document.getElementById("error_mess").style.display = 'none';
            } else {
                attempt += 1;
                document.getElementById("error_mess").style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById("error_mess").innerHTML = '<br><font color="#ff4040" onMouseover="ddrivetip(\'There is an error connecting. The game will continue trying to connect again.\')" onMouseout="hideddrivetip()"  style="cursor: pointer;">Error Code: ' + new XMLHttpRequest().status + '<br>Attempts: ' + attempt + '</font>';
            }

        }
    }
    setTimeout(function(){runme(icon);}, iconTimer);
}
setTimeout(function(){runme("mail");}, 5000);
setTimeout(function(){runme("news");}, 5000);
setTimeout(function(){runme("something");}, 5000);
/* And so on */
```

So, now your JavaScript sends a GET request to `auto.php` with the addition of the `icon` parameter. The PHP script will have to manage that, too.

```
//AUTO INCLUDE

$icon = urldecode($_GET['icon']);

$userids = $_GET['userid'];

$saturate = "/[^a-z0-9]/i";
$saturatesd = "/[^0-9]/i";
$sessionid = preg_replace($saturate,"",$sessionidbefore);
$userid = preg_replace($saturatesd,"",$userids);

switch($icon) {
    case "mail":
        $statustest = mysql_query("SELECT newmail,lastactive FROM login WHERE id = '$userids' LIMIT 1");
        $statustesttwo = mysql_fetch_array($statustest);
        $mails = $statustesttwo['newmail'];

        $last_active_1 = $statustesttwo['lastactive'];

        if ($mails == '0') {
            echo "<a id='inboxspan' href='/home.php?pageid=80'><img src='images/mail-yes.gif' style='border-style: none'></a>";
        } else {
            echo "<a id='inboxspan' href='/home.php?pageid=80'><img src='images/layout/mail-n.jpg' style='border-style: none'></a>";
        }
        break;

    case "news":
        $statustest = mysql_query("SOME OTHER SQL QUERY");
        $statustesttwo = mysql_fetch_array($statustest);

        /* check whatever you need to */

        if (/* something */) {
            echo "the HTML for the icon";
        } else {
            echo "the HTML for the other icon ";
        }
        break;

    /* And so on, again, covering all your 9 cases */

}
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What does encodeURIComponent(icon) do?

Comment: It's a function that encodes a string in order to use it as a parameter in an URL. A white space becomes %20, and so on. The PHP script has the corresponding `urldecode()` to get the original string back. By the way, I added a couple of single quotes I forgot, thanks to nl-x for the tip.

Comment: I see. BTW I just tried this with the first icon and it only updates the first time but doesn't update the second time??

Comment: That's odd. Did you use the single quotes I added in the first `setTimeout()`?

Comment: BTW, would running a check every second be bad?

Comment: I have edited the setTimeout functions (a known problem of scope I didn't think of). Could you try it? Oh, and a check every second seems definitely like overkill: your request might even need longer. I don't know what they are for exactly, but anything under five seconds is probably risky (in my opinion).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30087/discussion-between-sam-ham-and-aioros)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your exact problem is. Do you get an error?

What I quickly see is:

```
attempt += 1
```

Change this into

```
if (typeof attempt == "undefined") attempt = 0;
attempt ++;
```

So add the semi-colon `;` , and first check if the var already exists

( ++ is the same as += 1 )

Answer (score 1):

Is this function `runme` generated by PHP?

```
var str = "<?echo$id;?>";
var strhehe = "&rand=" + Math.random();
var strhehes = "&userid=<?echo$id;?>";
var strhehess = "&username=<?echo$name;?>";
```

Because if it is not, there is no way this code will work, because Javascript cannot interpret PHP.

In this case, you should put this as attributes of HTML elements and get'em with DOM.
When generating your HTML with PHP, do:

```
echo '<output id="data-id">' . $id . '<output>';
echo '<output id="data-user-id">' . $id . '<output>';
echo '<output id="data-user-name">' . $username . '<output>';
```

You can hide this elements with CSS. So then in your Javascript, you should do:

```
var str = document.getElementById('data-id').innerHTML;
var strhehe = "&rand=" + Math.random();
var strhehes = "&userid=" + document.getElementById('data-user-id').innerHTML;
var strhehess = "&username=" + document.getElementById('data-user-name').innerHTML;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, it is generated by PHP.